# C++ class merging, linker issue

Tags: c++, linker, undefined-behavior

Let's consider the following situation I've discovered today by browsing through a pretty large codebase (real source exemplified for the sake of example):

One of the teams created the following two files and a set of interfaces (`MoreBase`, `Base`). All is fine till this point.

*** file1.h ***

```
class MoreBase
{
public:
    MoreBase();
    virtual  ~MoreBase();
};

class Base : public MoreBase
{
public:
    virtual ~Base();
    virtual void func() const = 0;
};

class A : public Base
{
public:
    A();
    ~A();
    virtual void func() const;
};
```

*** file1.cpp ***

```
#include <iostream>
#include "file1.h"

using namespace std;

MoreBase::MoreBase() {  cout << "file 1 MoreBase::MoreBase " << (void*)this << endl; }
MoreBase::~MoreBase() { cout << "file 1 ~MoreBase::MoreBase " << (void*)this << endl;}

Base::~Base() { cout << "file 1 ~Base::Base " << (void*)this << endl; }

A::~A() { cout << "file1 ~A::A() "<< (void*)this << endl; }

A::A() { cout << "file 1 A::A() "<< (void*)this << endl; }

void A::func() const { cout << "file 1 A::func() "<< (void*)this << endl; }
```

But there is another team, which is in a totally different department, building, country, continent, developing something totally different... such as the following:

*** file2.h ***

```
int some2method();
```

*** file2.cpp ***

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base();
    virtual void something() const = 0;
};

class B : public Base
{
public:
    B();
    ~B();
    virtual void something() const;
};

B::~B() { cout << "file 2 B::~B() "<< (void*)this << endl; }

B::B() { cout << "file 2 B::B() "<< (void*)this << endl; }

void B::something() const { cout << "file 2 B::something() "<< (void*)this << endl; }

// VARIABLE
const Base& x = B(); // ***

int some2method()
{
    x.something();
    return 42;
}
```

*** main.cpp ***

```
#include "file2.h"

int main()
{
    some2method();    
}
```

And let's compile it like:

```
$ g++ -ggdb main.cpp file1.cpp file2.cpp -o test
```

and let's run:

```
 $ ./test
 file 1 MoreBase::MoreBase 0x6022f0
 file 2 B::B() 0x6022f0
 file 2 B::something() 0x6022f0
 file 2 B::~B() 0x6022f0
 file 1 ~Base::Base 0x6022f0
 file 1 ~MoreBase::MoreBase 0x6022f0
```

Don't you consider it weird that it constructs a `MoreBase` object that I never requested?

*Unfortunately* (1) the company develops one product, so all the source files are linked into one executable.

*Unfortunately* (2) `Base` is a very common name in the domain we work...

*Fortunately* (1) the line marked with `// ***` was to be found in `some2method()` and the application crashed **when compiled with GCC**. That's where I started the investigation (right now it's outside so doesn't even crash).

And *Obviously* the question: How on earth is this possible? Why did the linker merge two totally unrelated classes, although they have the misfortune to share the same name. Is this undefined behaviour, defined something or simply misfortune?

***EDIT***: I don't request a solution to the problem (it can be fixed with namespaces, or simply renaming the not public base class), I just want to know the root cause :)

Comment: This is the reason namespaces were invented. What happens is that all the symbols end up as 'weak' until the last bind into the executable and you can simply end up with the wrong definition 'winning', which causes the crash. The reason is that there is no way for the linker to truly know which class is the 'right' one, and they all look the same to it.

Comment: Sounds like UB. Doesn't this break the one-definition rule? Maybe you don't have multiple definitions error, because they are different classes, but still.. That's why the language supports `namespace`s, to avoid such problems.

Comment: I was about to ask if you're problem mysteriously vanishes if you tuck the class definitions in `file2.cpp` in an *anonymous* namespace. And I find it decidedly convenient you did *not* implement `Base::~Base()` in file2.cpp, which would/should/could have triggered a duplicate-symbol at link time in the first place.

Comment: @WhozCraig (1) The fact that I just only declared `Base::~Base()` in file2.cpp is due to the fact that I copied the "logic" of the existing code to this example. If Id remove the declaration of `Base::~Base()` in file2.cpp the output modifies, does not print out the destructor calls, only the MoreBase::MoreBase constructor.  Possibly the original developers saw the multiple definition error in the linking step and just got rid of it quickly :) (2) Tucking the definitions from file2.cpp into anonymous namespace gives: `file2.cpp:22: undefined reference to (anonymous namespace)::Base::~Base()`

Comment: @fritzone "If I'd remove the declaration" - I didn't say anything about removing the declaration. I said you never *implemented* the function in the first place. You declared it, but ever implemented it, and the linker found one anyway from a different translation unit. Had you implemented it the linker would probably have choked with a multiple-definition error. The linker error after wrapping up `file2.cpp` in an anonymous namespace exposes *exactly* what I just described. Sorry if the wording in my prior comment was foggy. Late here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this breaks the one definition rule, which entails UB. The way to protect against that is to use namspaces and in particular, put any private class definition (read inside a cpp-file) inside an anonymous namespace.

EDIT: Sorry, I just realized, that WhozCraig already provided the exact same answer in the comments

Comment: No problem, WhozCraig should have known that answers belong as an answer and not a comment. fritzone cannot accept a comment as the correct answer.

Comment: Indeed a very awkward way of violating the one definition rule . :)

Comment: @fritzone: Yes, but not uncommen in bigger projects. I hit that problem the first time, when I was writing some tests for a program containing many template classes. For the unit tests, I wrote a couple of different `struct test{}` in the `<class>_test.cpp` files and got errors all over the place, which didn't make any sense.